# Specifying mean and kernel function in Gaussian Process

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, machine-learning

As part of the Improved Machine Learning in Mathematica 11, Wolfram advertises the [Method "GaussianProcess"](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/improved-machine-learning/visualize-the-predictions-of-a-gaussian-process-mo.html) which can be used with Predict[] to obtain smooth Gaussian random fields. The screenshot below from the official documentation shows how this is applied.

However, I was wondering if I can somehow specify the mean function $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ and covariance kernel function $k(x_i, x_j)$? I cannot find it in the [documentation of Predict[]](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Predict.html), or anywhere else in the Wolfram documentation. Perhaps there is an undocumented option to provide the mean and kernel function?

I am referring $\mu$ and $k$ as used in this paper [this paper](http://rsta.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/371/1984/20110550).

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not yet possible to specify arbitrary covariance kernels. However, there are a few ways to control the kernel type. You can specify the type of covariance function using the `"CovarianceType"` suboption like so:

```
pred = Predict[data, 
  Method -> {
      "GaussianProcess", 
      "CovarianceType" -> "Linear"
  }
]
```

The possible kernels for `"CovarianceType"` are:

```
{
   "Periodic", "SquaredExponential", "RationalQuadratic", "Linear", 
   "Mattern5/2", "Mattern3/2", "NN", "WN"
}
```

You can also specify algebraic combinations of these kernels, such as:

```
"CovarianceType" -> "Linear" + "Periodic" * "RationalQuadratic"
```

Finally, there is the `"Composite"` option value, which will try and find a sensible combination of kernels that works well. Furthermore, there is the `"SearchMethod"` suboption for composite kernels, which can be set to `"Greedy"` or `"SimulatedAnnealing"`. E.g.:

```
Method -> {
      "GaussianProcess", 
      "CovarianceType" -> "Composite",
      "SearchMethod" -> "SimulatedAnnealing"
  }
```

After the predictor `pred` has been computed, you can investigate what it's using by evaluating:

```
pred[[1]]
```

## Edit

As far as I know, there is currently no implementation of mean functions, but I might be wrong about that.

## Edit 2

Since I answered this question, the documentation has been updated. Be sure to check it for any updates to the GaussianProcess method:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/method/GaussianProcess.html